# Should I apply for a position which I previously applied and had an initial interview?

Tags: job-search, postdocs, faculty-application, interview, non-tenure

I am on the job market again, in Mathematics.  I see a few job postings for positions which I applied for last year, and I had an initial interview for, but no second or campus interview.  These were either temporary or postdoc positions.

**Should I apply for these again, since I am still interested?**  Or is it a waste of my time, and I should take the lack of a second interview as my cue that they are not interested in me.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. The cost of an application is essentially free -- these days you don't even have to pay postage. Unless you were specifically told that you were categorically unsuitable (e.g., you had a felony conviction and the job required contact with minors) then there's no reason not to reapply.

<strike>It's more curious why the same job popped up again. Either the search failed or the candidate bailed after being hired. You might want to delicately inquire as to what happened.</strike>

You clarified that this is for a post-doc or other temporary position. In that case, there's all the more reason to reapply. While applying should just take you about an hour of your time to brush up the CV and letter since you did everything last year -- As aparente001 notes, you may want to invest just a bit more time to figure out what the committee is looking for and hone your application a bit more.

Comment: The reason why they are hiring for the same position is because these are temporary or postdoc positions.

Comment: An important factor in these decisions is whether the candidate's skills and interests match the slot they have available, and the needs.  It would be very helpful if you could find out more about the slot, so you can highlight the appropriate aspect of your prior experience.

Comment: @FelixY. That does not make it the same position. That makes it an equivalent position.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft The position has the exact same title and name to it, so I assumed I can call it "the same" but I'm not sure how you are defining equivalent in this case.